# What does an "ac coupled signal" mean?

Tags: capacitor, ac, signal, basic

I've heard this term many times from many different sources, but none of them gave me a definition.

Here is my understanding: "coupled" means "connected together". If two circuits are "capacitively coupled", that means they are connected with capacitors between them.

However, one question remains: What is an "ac coupled signal"? I know circuits can be coupled, but how can we couple a signal?

Answer (score 2):

The manner of "coupling" is referring to what signals can pass. An *AC coupled* system is also a *DC blocked* system. Similarly, a *DC coupled* system allows both the DC and AC components of the signal to pass through the system.

The relationship between *AC coupled* and *capacitively coupled* is in the use of a capacitor to achieved the *DC blocking* ability of the system. By inserting a capacitor in series with the signal, a slowly changing signal can no longer pass. This is a high-pass filter.

An example of this is the DC/AC/GND selection of an oscilloscope input. In *DC coupled* mode, there is no filtering other than that inherent in the probe/cable/input, meaning you can measure slowly changing signals and (inaccurately) measure DC voltages. In *AC coupled* mode, a capacitor is switched in series inside the oscilloscope, creating a high-pass filter, meaning you can more easily measure signals with a large DC offset. This is useful for measuring the small, fast transient of a switching power supply experiencing an output step load change (with a large DC offset) or many other signals. Finally, in *GND* mode, the internal switch disconnects the external input and grounds the internal circuitry.

Comment: So an _ac coupled signal_ is the ac part extracted from an original signal?

Comment: @sunqingyao exactly.

Comment: *"By inserting a capacitor in series with the signal, a slowly changing signal can no longer pass. This is a high-pass filter."*  - this isn't quite correct unless the assumptions are made explicit.